# How to append addtional rows to an exisitng Observable

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am trying to create expandable row similar to the angular example.
  [Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-expandable-table-rows?file=app%2Ftable%2Ftable.component.ts)

Currently, my data source is a BehaviorSubject that returns an Observable in the connect method.

How can I append additional rows to my existing code?

```
private gizmoSubject = new BehaviorSubject<Gizmo[]>([]);

  connect(collectionViewer: CollectionViewer): Observable<Gizmo[]> {
    const rows = [];
    this.gizmoSubject.forEach(x => rows.push(x, { detailRow: true, x }));
    console.log(rows);
    return of(rows);

    // This was the original code.
    //return this.gizmoSubject.asObservable();
  }
```

I first attempted to handle this when I get the data from the API, but I could not get it to work there either.

```
loadGizmos(findParams: GizmoParameters) {

  this.loadingSubject.next(true);

  this.gizmoService.findGizmos(findParams)
    .pipe(
      finalize(() => this.loadingSubject.next(false))
    )
    .subscribe(x => {
      this.gizmoSubject.next(x);
    });  
}
```

- I tried using the map in this method but I couldn't seem to get the syntax correct.  Would I be better off handling this type of manipulation here as opposed to the connect method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private rows = []

private gizmoSubject = new BehaviorSubject<Gizmo[]>([]);

connect(collectionViewer: CollectionViewer): Observable<Gizmo[]> {
  return this.gizmoSubject.asObservable().pipe(
    map(x => {
      this.rows.push(x, { detailRow: true, x })
      return rows
    }
  )
}
```

Comment: Should be: x.forEach(item => this.rows.push(item, { detailRow: true, item }));

But I think I understand how to attack this the next time.